# Why does 2nd link introduce ambiguity when using common dim table?

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I have tables as follows:

```
  DimLocation 

  DimProduct

  DimCustomer

  FactSales
```

DimLocation filters both product and customer.

Product and customer filter factSales.

This looks like a diamond schema.

Power BI only allows me to make 1 Link as active: location to product Or location to customer.

Both cannot be made active as it says it will introduce ambiguity. I am looking for simple example of why it will introduce ambiguity.

My thinking is that selecting a location will filter both product and customer. Then both these tables will filter the factSales such that sales common to both dims should be kept. Therefore there is no ambiguity. Why does power bi think it will cause ambiguity?

[image]

Comment: It's a strange requirement. What does location mean with regards to Product? For example you pick location "Sydney". You want to filter products warehoused(?) in Sydney and Customers with an address of Sydney? That wouldn't be very useful if for example you just wanted to see all customers in Sydney regardless of where the product is. It's ambiguous because this kind of model implies that you don't want to apply location to two completely different dimensions at once.

Comment: You can actually do what you want in Power BI but it makes no sense. Either that or the data is modelled incorrectly.

Comment: Also you appear to have `id` in your fact as well - why not join location directly to the fact?

Comment: that is factid, not locationid.